# Is there any wireless flash trigger compatible with the Sigma EF-610 DG ST flash and my Canon 1000D?

Tags: flash, sigma, wireless-triggers, canon-1000d

I am looking for a wireless flash trigger. I use a Canon 1000D camera and Sigma EF-610 DG ST flash.

[I checked](http://dpanswers.com/content/genrc_flash_comp.php) that there are several problems when the flash is used with manual wireless triggers.

So, does anyone know if there is a wireless trigger compatible (with TTL at list) with my flash? If it is cheap

For example, will this one work?: [Phottix Strato™ II Multi 5-in-1](http://www.phottix.com/en/phottix-strato-ii-multi.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use TTL flash with a Canon camera you need a flash that would be compatible with Canon's E-TTL system. If you want to use a Sigma EF-610 DG ST flash it needs to be the Canon version. The Sigma EF-610 DG ST flash is also offered in Nikon, Pentax, Sony/Minolta, and Sigma versions. The following assumes you have the Canon version of the Sigma EF-610 DG ST flash.

You also need a TTL compatible set of triggers. The Phottix Strato™ II Multi 5-in-1 Wireless Flash Trigger is a *manual control only* trigger set. They won't allow you to use E-TTL.

There are other cheap flash trigger sets that will allow you to use E-TTL with a Canon EOS DSLR and a Canon E-TTL compatible flash such as you Sigma EF-610 DG ST.

The Yongnuo 622C is one such system. Each unit costs about $40 in the U.S. You can either use two [YN-622C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0090BSSZO) transceivers with one transmitting from the camera's hot shoe and the other receiving attached to the flash or you can use a [YN-622C-TX](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MFDO2DG) transmitter on the camera and a YN-622C with the flash.

The advantage of the transmit only YN-622C-TX is that it has a LCD display panel that makes it much easier to change settings compared to using the YN-622C which only has a few buttons and indicator lights and requires many of the settings to be made using the flash control section of the camera's menu. The LCD display on the YN-622C-TX is both more intuitive to use and faster to access than the camera's external flash control menu, especially if you are controlling multiple flashes in different groups and want to use some manually and others in E-TTL mode.

Note: Models such as the 1000D/Rebel XS that was introduced before the EOS 5D Mark II in late 2008 do not have the in camera menu to control external flashes. This would severely limit the usefulness of the YN-622 system without a YN-622C-TX transmitter.

I use the YN-622C system. I have a single YN-622C-TX that I use on the camera's hot shoe to control several YN-622C triggers attached to various flashes. They work with any flash that is Canon E-TTL compatible: My Canon 430EX II and 580EX II, as well as several Canon versions of Yongnuo flashes. The YN685 flash even has a 622C receiver built in, so there is no need to attach a trigger to it. I've been very happy with the capabilities and performance of the 622C system, especially for the affordable price at which they sell.

The [Godox X1C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EIYBCI2) (C=Canon) is another such system that is fairly affordable. The Godox X1T-C offers a user interface with more information than the base X1-C transmitter, similar to the YN-622C-TX in comparison to the YN-622C. Unfortunately, as of September 2016, the Godox system seems to still be in a "beta" stage of development. Every time they update the firmware to solve one bug it seems they create another bug in the process. If they can ever get all of the kinks worked out it appears to be a very promising system, but for now it seems to be not quite ready for prime time.

Comment: There's a Godox X1R-C receiver you can put on the foot of a flash. One Adorama Q&A says it's compatible with 580EX and 600EX-RT, so not sure your final statement is correct.

Comment: Are you sure the Adorama reference is with regard to E-TTL or only for manually firing a 580EX (II?) or 600EX-RT?

Comment: @inkista Buried in the Godox article at Flash Havoc which you cite in your answer: "NOTE – X1T transmitters units can not currently provide TTL with alternate version X1R receivers (with TTL speedlite mounted on top)."

Comment: Keep on reading the comments. :) That note basically means you won't get TTL if you use a Sony or Nikon transmitter & camera with a Canon flash and receiver; i.e., the triggers can't translate TTL between systems. They apparently do, however, still perform HSS. See also [the X1-C announcement](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-x1-c-ttl-triggers-for-canon-announced/), where TTL is one of the called-out features, as well as compatibility with OEM Canon flashes.

Comment: Balance that with "Manny's" comment to the X1-C announcement you linked. Better yet, read all of the comments. It seems the X1-C system is still in the "beta" stage of development. For example, how would someone buying an X1-C via eBay know they were getting the more up to date version that has a long enough locking pin or getting old stock of the original release that had a short locking pin?

Comment: Also "Note: Pre-2012 models such as the 1000D/Rebel XS ... do not have the in camera menu..." technically incorrect. The demarcation for the menu is **Digic 4**; there are a lot of Digic 4 models pre-2012, such as my 5DMkII, which _do_ have the menu. The 1000D lacks the menu because it's Digic III, not because it's pre-2012. Pre-2012 also isn't that meaningful with 622s, since the 622s add some 2012 features such as Gr mode for pre-2012 cameras.

Comment: Yeah, I got the release dates of the 5DII and 5DIII confused. I'm fairly certain only the YN-622C-TX can add group mode capability to the models without the in camera external flash control menu because the YN-622C lacks the interface to do so.

Comment: Actually, you could use Mixed Mode on the YN-622C (by holding down the channel button for a few seconds), but it was a PITA to use and hard to see what you had set, vs. the YN-622C-TX.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a wireless flash trigger. I use a Canon 1000D camera and Sigma EF-610 DG ST flash.
>
> [I checked](http://dpanswers.com/content/genrc_flash_comp.php) that there are several problems when the flash is used with manual wireless triggers.

Huh? That page you linked to lists issues using optical "peanut"-style slaves with an OEM Canon EX flash. This is not what most folks think of when you use the words "wireless flash triggers" which, most commonly, means **radio** triggers.

> So, does anyone know if there is a wireless trigger compatible ... with my flash?

Generally speaking, as long as your flash is fully compatible in TTL with your camera, it should work with any radio flash triggers that are compatible in TTL with your camera. Radio triggers these days communicate the flash hotshoe signals on the camera to the foot of the flash. As long as the flash's foot can "talk" TTL to the trigger, it should work.

The Strattos are not TTL-capable; they are manual-only triggers. Phottix's TTL triggers are the Odin (currently, the Odin II). There a lot of possible trigger that would work for you, including the Yongnuo YN-622, Pixel Kings, RadioPopper PX units, and the PocketWizard Flex TT5/Mini TT1 triggers. (See also [the Flash Havoc gear guide on TTL and remote manual radio triggers](http://flashhavoc.com/flash-trigger-guide-ttl/)).  However, at this very moment, probably your best bet would be the Godox X1(C) triggers.

Because [Godox has a triggering *system*](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-system-overview/) (unlike Yongnuo's three incompatible systems) with transceivers/receivers built into most of their lights, with which you've got a lot of room to grow. They make a low-cost manual flash (TT600), which, like the YN-660, has a built-in transceiver that allows for remote power control, but unlike the YN-660, also gives you HSS with the X1, and works in conjunction with the TTL/HSS lights/triggers Godox offers.

If you go Yongnuo and later decide to add TTL/HSS triggering and units into your scheme, then you can't use the YN-560/660 lights/triggers, but must buy equivalent YN-622 gear, as the two systems don't talk to each other directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @inkista, but the Sigma EF-610 DG ST flash does not have a slave mode, the Sigma EF-610 DG Super does.

Comment: @ChesuCR Thanks. I'll remove that from the answer.